# Django Controller do download a static file

Tags: python, django, xml, django-views

I have a controller in my web app like this:

```
    def all_trials(request):
       return HttpResponseRedirect(URL_TO_XML_IN_STATIC)
```

How can I change my code to controller have the feature to download the file and not open the file in web browser?

Comment: The [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/request-response/#telling-the-browser-to-treat-the-response-as-a-file-attachment) specifically addresses this issue.

Answer (score 0):

like this?

```
def download_xml(request):
     xml = f.open(xml_file, "r")

     resp = HttpResponse(xml,
        mimetype = 'text/xml'
        )

    resp['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=file.xml'
    return resp
```